# Restricting U-turns using ArcMap and Network Analyst

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, network-analyst, turns

I am using ArcMap 10.7. I would like to calculated routing for my input data. I created a turn features (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-turn-feature.htm) and also turn feature that represents a U-turn (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/network-analyst/creating-a-turn-feature-representing-u-turns.htm).
I created Network Dataset and made turn restriction attribute (Name: turn, usage: restriction, units: unknown, dataType: Boolean. In the Evaluators I used: Source: turn, element: turn, Type: constant, value: use restriction).

My network recognizes and uses all forbidden turns, except U - turns.  If I use the Network Identify, I can see that my network does not recognize the object which I drew as Utrun as forbidden (it says "Traversable" instead of "Prohibited").

Does anyone know why?

And also, in the properties of Network Dataset under travel mode I set: U-Turns at Junctions: Not Allowed.